# Hooks: admin_footer and admin_print_footer_scripts not working?

Tags: wp-admin, admin

Tried them both and they don't seem to be working, am I missing something?

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'jupload_scripts');
    wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.6');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );
}
```

Comment: You have to `wp_register_script()` earlier. Split this between two functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Wordpress Codex its best to register and queue your scripts with the hook dedicated for them, even if you want your script to be added to footer.

So the correct way of doing it will be:

```
function jupload_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.6', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'jupload_scripts' );
```

Comment: @Hameedullah So admin_print_scripts is ok but admin_print_footer_scripts is not? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, for some reason the scripts that you queue in admin_print_footer_scripts hook are not printed by wp. So you have to queue them in the admin_print_scripts hook, just make sure if you want them to be printed in footer set the last $in_footer argument to true as in the above example.

Comment: @Hameedullah Ah, sorry, didn't see that first. Thanks alot, works like a charm!

Comment: Also: WordPress *already bundles* a version of jQuery-UI. It is imperative, *especially* in the *backend*, that you *first deregister* the core-bundled jQuery-UI, by calling `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui' )`, before registering/enqueueing your own version. Also, if you are going to do this, do it judiciously. The specific jQuery/jQuery-UI version combination is used in WordPress due to extensive bug testing. If you change versions of one or the other, you are *highly likely* to encounter version-conflict issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Chip. I wasn't entirely sure, since in WP they call it jquery-ui-core. I thought there were some difference. Anyway, do I neeed to include jquery-ui.css on my own, or is that taken care of aswell?

Comment: you just need to queue it to make sure its available when you need it, wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core') most of the time it is loaded in wp admin

Comment: Well, maybe you're okay, then. Here's the [full list of core-bundled/registered scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress). It is indeed `jquery-ui-core`, rather than just `jquery-ui`. But you'll still need to ensure no conflicts between the scripts themselves (if applicable).